# JSON fail and continue code

Tags: javascript, json

I am pulling json from an external website. I grab a string with this code from their JSON as I parse it:

```
breweryName = data.data[i].breweries[0].name;
```

The problem is that one of the entries in the JSON I receive does not have a value for breweries[0].name.

How Can I keep executing the code? Despite one bad entry? I tried this:

```
if(data.data[i].breweries[0].name === "undefined"){
   breweryName = "N/A"
}
else{
   breweryName = data.data[i].breweries[0].name;

}
```

That still fails

Comment: Not sure why I was voted down as usual.

Answer (score 0):

this first checks if there are `breweries` at given index `i` and also if there are nested elements, by checking for the size property; within the inner loop, it checks for the `name` property with `typeof()`:

```
if(
   typeof(data.data[i].breweries) !== 'undefined' &&
   data.data[i].breweries.size > 0
){
      /* traverse the individual entries */
      data.data[i].breweries.forEach(function(v, i){
         if(typeof(v.name) !== 'undefined'){
            /* the element has a name property */
         } else {
            /* name property is absent */
         }
      });
}
```

next time please provide some sample data, that makes answering more easy.

because it might be array or object... which requires different treatment.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, use the typeof function

```
if (typeof data.data[i].breweries === "undefined" ||
  typeof data.data[i].breweries[0] === "undefined" ||
  typeof data.data[i].breweries[0].name === "undefined")
```

you may also want to include

```
if (data.data[i].breweries[0].name.trim() === "")
```

to check for names that are present, but empty.

A shortcut approach may work as well ...

```
breweryName = data.data[i].breweries[0].name || "N/A"
```

Comment: The error is the result of accessing the name property of undefined which is what [0] equals. None of these approaches shown solve this issue nor allude to its presence.

Comment: @TravisJ OP Asks 
"The problem is that one of the entries in the JSON I receive does not have a value for breweries[0].name." why you decided that accessed property `name ` of undefined ???

Comment: **typeof** allows you to test for the presence of a variable or property.  If typeof returns undefined, you know that the variable has not been defined and can avoid accessing it which would cause an error.  This approach is a common way to handle the issue.

Comment: If it helps the breweries[0].name just does not exist for one of the values returned in the JSON